# Bloquear la tecla coma "," en Android Studio XML

Tags: android-studio, xml

Quiero evitar que un usuario ingrese una coma “,” en un `EditText`, investigue que se puede hacer con la propiedad de `android:digits=””` pero se tiene que meter los caracteres restantes, habrá una propiedad para que bloquee esa propiedad en el XML?.
Gracias.

Este es mi `EditText`:

```
 <xxxx_android_v1.com.xxxx.sap.xxxx.xxxx_v1.Utility.DTWCustomEditText
                            android:id="@+id/textViewDescGuardar"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:ems="8"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:maxLength="50"
                            android:digits="@string/caracteres"
                            android:inputType="textPersonName" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Bloquear el agregar caracteres en un `EditText`:**

Programaticamente puedes realizarlo no permitiendo ciertos caracteres, puedes agregar un [InputFilter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.html) para evitar escribir determinado carácter en un `EditText`, primero crea el [InputFilter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.html) para validar si contiene el carácter que no deseas y retornar un String vació al tratar de escribirlo:

```
private String charactersForbiden = ","; //*Caracter o caracteres no permitidos.

private InputFilter inputfilter = new InputFilter() {

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

        if (source != null && charactersForbiden .contains(("" + source))) {
            return "";
        }
        return null;
    }
};
```

Ahora asignalo a tu `EditText`:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { inputfilter });
```

Incluso puedes evitar se escriban otros caracteres agregandolos a la variable

```
  private String charactersForbiden = ",%$ñ[*]";
```

---

Al agregar un [InputFilter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.html) la propiedad  `android:maxLength` se deshabilita, pero puedes agregar esta propiedad en el filtro para volver a habilitarla:

```
myEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.LengthFilter(50), inputfilter });
```

Comment: Si esta bien, pero no respeta mi MaxLength="50"

Comment: revisa mi actualización puedes agregar esa opción en el filtro. @Javierfr

Comment: Muchas gracias por ayudarme @Jorgesys

Comment: @Javierfr un placer, saludos Javier!